# JAXBContext and @XmlNsForm annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-binding

Please shed some light on JAXBContext configutation. 
Given:

- customer library `com.mycompany.user01234` with several
  JAXB-annotated classes
- all classes are simple POJOs located in the same package
- classes are annotated by `@XmlType`

Customer marshals instance of `com.mycompany.user01234.UserClass1.class` to the server via web service endpoint. On the server side I do the following:

```
JAXBContext jbc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.mycompany.user01234")
Unmarshaller um = jbc.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<Object> element = um.unmarshal(source, Object.class);
Object customerInput = element.getValue();
```

And it works fine **ONLY** if I patch customer library with following `package-info.java`:

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mycompany.user01234;
```

To my shame I havent found any clear explanation of what this `@XmlNsForm` annotation is and how it affects unmarshalling process. This is the first question.

The second question is whether it is possible (in the given layout) to put that `QUALIFIED` value into some properties or defaults for `JAXBContext` or use other non-declarative means allowing to get rid of `package-info.java`.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It corresponds exactly to the `elementFormDefault` attribute of an `<xs:schema>` element (i.e., the top-level element of an XML Schema document). What it does (with that constant) is state that *elements* from the namespace defined by the schema should be rendered with a qualifier (i.e., as `<foo:bar>` instead of `<bar>`); the exact way that the namespace is declared will also vary between the two styles. In terms of the XML infoset, the two styles are completely equivalent; if namespaces are declared correctly in the XML, JAXB should be equally happy (I believe it should only use the value when serializing).

You might want to try making your `JAXBContext` by passing in the class that you are expecting so that you are a little less reliant on discovery code (assuming it's a `FooBar` class that's really being produced):

```
JAXBContext jbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FooBar.class);
FooBar customerInput = (FooBar) jbc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(source);
```

(The above code is abstracted from things that I do in my code's test suite that *definitely* already work.)

Comment: thanks for reply, it makes things much cleaner, time to polish my xml utils.

Comment: +1 - The following article may also help you with JAXB and namespaces:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html